# Cooling of compressed air

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, cooling

If we compress air from $p_1=1bar$ with starting temperature $T_1=20°C$, the pipes behind the compressor become usually "very" hot. However, if we start at $T_1=20°C$ and $p_1=10bar$ and we decompress the air to $p_2 = 1bar$, the temperature drop is rather "small". This can be seen be using the Joules-Thomson coefficient $\mu\approx 0.2 K/bar$ of nitrogen [image: Wiki] (from [Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect#/media/File:Joule-Thomson_curves_2.svg).  What is the reason for this huge asymmetry? Does a technical method exists, which circumvent this and allows to achieve low temperatures?

**Background information:** Unfortunately, I cannot use a vortex tube.

Comment: You are decompressing by flowing the air through a valve, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be my first option. However, if there is a clever way to cool the air by using an other technical feasible option, I'd love to learn about this option.

Comment: You can make the gas cool down by making it do work, like passing it through turbine as it expands.

Comment: Without reading the chart, I would like some clarity on the wording of the question. For heating you reference the "pipes behind the compressor" but for cooling you switch to "temperature drop". Since cooling is not assumed to happen in the "pipes behind the compressor", you would likely be referring to a different place of measurement for the temperature. Do you refer to the valve through which the air is released? Or to the air in the final chamber? Or the temperator of the hose/pipe at the nearest point to the release location? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, and here's how.

You first compress the gas. You will notice that it heats up. You hold it in its compressed state and let the heat leak away into the surroundings, so now you have compressed gas at *room temperature*. You then bleed it through a small valve down to atmospheric pressure and it gets nice and cold.

The cooling effect can be magnified by chilling the hot gas with water from a tap, lake, or stream if that water is colder than the surrounding air.